# What is the difference between a bastion host and a dual homed host?

Tags: firewalls

From what I read, I understood that both the bastion host and the dual homed host are special computers that act as a link between the local network and the internet, so what is the difference between them?

Comment: A dual-homed host can be anything with 2 active network interfaces, whether meant to protect networks or not. A Bastion host is one with protection as a purpose.

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/146891/firewalling-screened-host-bastion-host

Comment: Not really. I've already seen that question before asking this one. I could understand the Screened Host well, my problem is understanding the difference between bastion host and dual homed host, since they seem to behave the same way topologically-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit like asking what's the difference between a defense counsel and an attorney.  An attorney is a person who has studied law and is licensed to practice it; defense counsel is the role an attorney can play in a specific trial.

"Dual-homed" describes the networking configuration of a host that has interfaces in two networks. "Bastion" describes the role it plays: provide safe, controlled external access to resources in one of those networks to authorized clients in the other.

Comment: So you are saying a dual-homed host can act as a Bastion? When I studied them, they were separated and seemed like two different defensive mechanisms. This explanation makes sense.

Comment: No. A bastion is usually has a presence on at least 2 networks - but its purpose is specifically to control access access between those networks and it has been hardened to do so. A dual-homed host simply has a presence in more than one network,

Comment: @symcbean and not only that, a dual-homed host can be on the same network