# A bastion host is a firewall?

Tags: firewalls

I don't understand the difference between a bastion host and a firewall. I think it could be related to the different level of ISO/OSI they work on: a bastion host works on application level (with proxying capabilities too), but a firewall can work also on L3/L4 layer. Please correct me if my assertions are wrong.

Comment: A quick search would get you this answer https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/146891/firewalling-screened-host-bastion-host

Comment: and : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host